# Cannot connect to SystemDSN ODBC datasource IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, odbc

I have configured odbc datasource as System DSN.
It works fine by itself and from Visual studio.

When I try to start applicattion under the IIS 7 on connection I get an error:

> ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].
>
> ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout
>   expired
>
> ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Application runs as different user - this user has no access premonitions to somewhere that ODBC uses.

I changed ApplicationPool identity to ran as administrator - this solved my problem. This was the fast solution. At least this is dirrection to dig. :)